# How to use the "new line" command when converting a list into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, iterable

I'm converting a string into a DataFrame, but when reading as csv, and then a list, the string iterates each letter as a new row in the DataFrame.  How can I code where a new row should begin?

'overs' variable is a string:

```
BASKETBALL - NBA
SPREAD
MONEY
TOTAL
...
```

The following code returns a DataFrame with one letter per row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(reader(overs)))
```

Returns:

```
col_name: 0 
data: 0      B
1      A
2      S
3      K
4      E
      ..
250     
251    P
252    L
253    A
254    Y
Name: 0, Length: 255, dtype: object
```

Comment: pandas has the "read_csv" function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.split('\n')` which will return you a list with each element split on new line. But like others said, why not just use `pandas`' `.read_csv()`?

```
import pandas as pd

overs = '''BASKETBALL - NBA
SPREAD
MONEY
TOTAL'''

df = pd.DataFrame(overs.split('\n'))
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                  0
0  BASKETBALL - NBA
1            SPREAD
2             MONEY
3             TOTAL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.read_csv` and use `header=None` so that it won't make the first value a column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('overs.txt', header=None)
print(df)
```